# Solve the recurrence of T(n) = 3T(n/5) + T(n/2) + 2^n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am solving the recurrence of T(n) under the assumption that T(n) is contact for n <= 2. I started to solve this T(n) with the tree-method since we cannot use the master method here, but when I do the tree I am of course calculating the time C for this T(n) but my C-s are very non-trivial and weird, so I get for

`c = 2^n and then for the next c I get ' 3 * 2^(n/5) + 2^(n/3)`

And I don't how to solve with these values, is there anything that I am doing wrong or what procedure should I follow in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reduce the number of terms down as much as you can.

`3 * 2^(n/5) + 2^(n/3) = 3 * (2^(1/5) * 2^n) + (2^(1/3) * 2^n)`

Then combine all the coefficients together.

`(3 * 2^(1/5)) * 2^n + (2^(1/3)) * 2^n`

Notice that the common factor is `2^n`. So you would get:

`(3 * 2^(1/5) + 2^(1/3)) * 2^n`

and I'm going to name the first part of the product as `constant` which 
will give us:

`constant * 2^n` which is just `T(2^n)` because the constant is insignificant as the size of n gets very large.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the case. As `T(n)` is increasing we know that `T(n/2) > T(n/5)`. Hence, `T(n) < 4T(n/2) + 2^n`. Now, you can use master theorem, and say that `T(n)=O(2^n)`. On the other hand, without this replacement, as there exists `2^n` in `T(n)`, we can say `T(n) = \Omega(2^n)`. Therefore, `T(n) = \Theta(2^n)`.